# Paging SELECT query results from Cassandra in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

During my research I have come across this JIRA for Spring-Data-Cassandra: 
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-56

Now, according to the post above, currently SDC is not supporting Pagination in the Spring App due to structure of Cassandra. However, I'm thinking, if I can pull the entire rows list into a Java List, can I Paginate that list ? I don't have much experience in Spring, but is there something I am missing when I assume this can be done ?

Answer (score 3):

Cassandra does not support pagination in the sense of pointing to a specific page (limit/offset) but generates a continuation token (`PagingState`) that is a set of `byte`s. Pulling a `List` of records will load all records in memory and possibly exhaust your memory (depending on the amount of data).

Spring Data Cassandra 1.5.0 RC1 comes with a [streaming API](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.html#stream-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) in [CassandraTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.5.0.RC1/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.html):

```
Iterator<Person> it = template.stream("SELECT * FROM person WHERE … ;", Person.class);

while(it.hasNext()) {
   // …
}
```

`CassandraTemplate.stream(…)` will return an `Iterator` that operates on an underlying `ResultSet`. The DataStax driver uses a configurable fetch-size (`5000` rows by default) for bulk fetching. Streaming data access can fetch as much or as little data as you require to process data. Data is not retained by the driver nor Spring Data Cassandra, and once the fetched bulk is retrieved from the `Iterator`, the underlying `ResultSet` will fetch the next bulk itself.

The other alternative is using `ResultSet` directly that gives you access to `PagingState` and do all the continuation/paging business yourself. You would lose all the higher level benefits of Spring Data Cassandra.